# Define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL using the LIKE word

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How can I make a custom order where I sort the rows by `NAME` where the first rows' name has Bob in it followed by rows with name of Alex in it?
To explain what exactly I mean: I have made the following query to sort result if NAME = 'Bob' and if NAME = 'Alex':

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY CASE `NAME`
         WHEN 'Bob' THEN 1
         WHEN 'Alex' THEN 2
         ELSE 3
         END
```

But this only works when the NAME is exactly equal to Bob or Alex. I want to modify it to sort if the NAME has Bob or Alex in it, essentially if `NAME LIKE '%Bob%'` and `NAME LIKE '%Alex%'`. I tried something like the following but it does not work.

```
ORDER BY CASE `NAME`
         WHEN LIKE '%Bob%' THEN 1
         WHEN LIKE '%Alex%' THEN 2
         ELSE 3
         END
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: You're using `case` as a simple expression, use the *searched case* expression.

Comment: Valid SQL, but not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other form of `CASE` where you specify a condition in `WHEN` rather than a value.

```
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN NAME LIKE '%Bob%' THEN 1
         WHEN NAME LIKE '%Alex%' THEN 2
         ELSE 3
         END
```